# Calculator program keeps resulting with the answer "0"?

Tags: java

Okay so, I've written this code and gone over it many times to see if I can find my error. Unfortunately, I cannot find it and am becoming frustrated with myself. I've decided to post my code online. This is the actual Calculator class with the methods. The input class (not on this post) gets a user input and returns it as a string. Can someone please help me? Thanks bros.

```
public class Calculate extends UserInput{

int num1;
int num2;
int returnValue;
String operation;
String userInput1;
String userInput2;

public void calculate() {
    userInput1 = getUserInput("Enter a number: ");
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(userInput1); //Changing userInput to int
    operation = getUserInput("Enter an operation (+,-,*, or /): ");
    userInput2 = getUserInput("Enter a second number: "); //Changing second userInput to int
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(userInput2);

    if(operation == "+") {
        addition(num1, num2);
    } else if (operation == "-") {
        subtraction(num1, num2);
    } else if (operation == "*") {
        multiplication(num1, num2);
    } else if (operation == "/") {
        division(num1, num2);
    }

    System.out.println("Result: " + returnValue);
}

public double addition(int x, int y) {
    returnValue = x + y;
    return returnValue;
}

public double subtraction(int x, int y) {
    returnValue = x - y;
    return returnValue;
}

public double multiplication(int x, int y) {
    returnValue = x * y;
    return returnValue;
}

public double division(int x, int y) {
    returnValue = x / y;
    return returnValue;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fix to my problem! Thanks community!

```
    if(operation .equals("+")) {
        returnValue = addition(num1, num2);
    } else if (operation .equals("-")) {
        returnValue = subtraction(num1, num2);
    } else if (operation .equals("*")) {
        returnValue = multiplication(num1, num2);
    } else if (operation .equals("/")) {
        returnValue = division(num1, num2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(operation.equals("+")) {
    addition(num1, num2);
} else if (operation.equals("-")) {
    subtraction(num1, num2);
} else if (operation.equals("*")) {
    multiplication(num1, num2);
} else if (operation.equals("/")) {
    division(num1, num2);
}
```

Comment: You might want to point out integer division as well.

Comment: When I edit my code to match yours, I still get the output "0.0" no matter what I do. Is there any other solution?

Comment: `if operation.equals ("+")`

Comment: Solved! Thanks Jason and Wombat!